# Number theory division proof, powers of 2

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

Ok, for some reason I'm getting stuck in what might be an easy question.

Here's the problem:
If a and b>2 are positive integers, prove that ${ 2^{a}+1 \over 2^{b} -1} $ is not an integer.

My solution (I'm not sure I'm right):
Let ${ 2^{a}+1 \over 2^{b} -1} $ = $x$ where $x$ is an integer. What this problem is asking us, if seen under another light is to prove that $2^{b} -1$ does not divide $2^{a} -1$.
Let's assume the contrary. Then the gcd of $ 2^{b} -1$ and $2^{a}+1$, has to be $2^{b} -1.$ 
$gcd(2^{b} -1, 2^{a}+1)= gcd(2^{a}+1 +2^{b}-1, 2^{b}-1) = gcd(2^{a} + 2^{b}, 2^{b}-1) = gcd(2^{a-b} +1, 2^{b}-1)= ...= gcd(2^{a-b*k} +1, 2^{b}-1)$

we go on up to $k$ where $k$ is $a=b*k +r$. We clearly see that $gcd(2^{a-b*k} +1, 2^{b}-1) = gcd(2^{r} +1, 2^{b}-1) =\=  2^{b}-1$ which contradicts with our assumption. Thus, ${ 2^{a}+1 \over 2^{b} -1} $ is not an integer.

Comment: The proof is basically fine. You will have to explain why $2^b-1$ does not divide $2^r+1$. It is quite easy, but you will need to use $b\gt 2$. There are more efficient ways to write out your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression $a^b-1$ has a unique algebraic divisor for each divisor of b.  Because a^b+1 is a divisor of $a^{2b}-1$, but not of $a^b-1$, it means that $a^b+1$ comprises of divisors connected to even divisors of b, while the denominator contains also odd divisors of b.  Therefore the denominator can never divide the numerator.

Answer (score 0):

The divisors of Fermat numbers are Proth primes it is in the form of $k*2^n + 1$ as long as k is odd and $k < 2^n$. Proth numbers like Proth primes are obviously not Mersenne numbers, it is easy to see the diffrence as binary numbers, Proth numbers has at least $2^1$ bit as zero while Mersennes are all one. I've looked up Wolfram Mathworld for the definition of Proth primes.